# If $f(z)$ is entire and $|f''(z)| \leq 5$. Show that $f$ must have the form of $az^2 +bz +c$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

This might be a completely incorrect approach, but since we have that  $|f''(z)| \leq 5$, can we integrate both sides twice and obtain that $|f(z)| \leq \frac{5z^2}{2} +cz +c$ for c being some constant?. Then by taking $|z| = R$ we would have that $|f(z)| \leq \frac{5R^2}{2} +cR +c$ and then move into applying cauchys estimate here, or is that a wrong way to approach this? I have a feeling I can't just integrate right away, or that integrating immediately is the wrong approach for some reason.

Comment: Hint: apply Liouville's theorem to $f''$.

Comment: well, since its bounded and entire we know that $f''$ is constant correct?

Comment: Correct. Now, if $f''(z)=C$, what can possibly be $f'(z)$? What can possibly be $f(z)$?

Comment: well, since $f''(z) =C$ we would have that $f'(z) = Cz +C_1$. Integrating again we would get that $f(z) = \frac{Cz^2}{2} +C_1z +C_2$. Where all of them are $\in \mathbb{C}$ right?

Comment: ... and that, pretty much, completes your proof!

Comment: Thats sick I didn't even think to use louiville here, thank you so much, really, I appreciate it!